# How to visualize connected status reports per 5 minutes

Tags: azure-iot-hub, kql

Iot Hub sends connected and disconnected events to a log analytics workspace.

How can we create a diagram using a log analytics kusto query that shows the availability of a device during the day with a 5 minute sampling?

Source data looks like this:

| OperationName | DeviceId | TimeGenerated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| deviceConnect | device1 | 2022-09-22T09:43:20 |
| deviceDisconnect | device1 | 2022-09-22T09:53:20 |
| deviceDisconnect | device2 | 2022-09-22T09:55:20 |
| deviceConnect | device3 | 2022-09-22T10:00:20 |
| deviceConnect | device4 | 2022-09-22T10:43:20 |

...

Resulting data set should be like:

| Interval | DeviceId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... assuming all devices disconnected |  |  |
| 2022-09-22T09:40:00 | device1 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:40:00 | device2 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:40:00 | device3 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:40:00 | device4 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:45:00 | device1 | Connected |
| 2022-09-22T09:45:00 | device2 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:45:00 | device3 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:45:00 | device4 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:50:00 | device1 | Connected |
| 2022-09-22T09:50:00 | device2 | Connected |
| 2022-09-22T09:50:00 | device3 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:50:00 | device4 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:55:00 | device1 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:55:00 | device2 | Connected |
| 2022-09-22T09:55:00 | device3 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:55:00 | device4 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:00:00 | device1 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:00:00 | device2 | Disconnected |
| 2022-09-22T09:00:00 | device3 | Connected |
| 2022-09-22T09:00:00 | device4 | Connected |
| ... |  |  |

Status column can then be projected to Availability 100% or 0%.

Comment: Why make things more complicated instead of making them simpler? What's your endgame here?

Comment: I would like to create a time diagram on the availability of a particular device

Comment: Welocome to the https://xyproblem.info/ club :-)

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution.
Each device state is 0 or 1.
The graphs of the devices overlap.

```
let t = datatable(OperationName:string, DeviceId:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    "deviceConnect"    ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:43:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:53:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device2" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:55:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device3" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:00:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device4" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:43:20")
];
// Solution starts here
let resolution = 5m;
let TimeGenerated_start = toscalar(t | summarize bin(min(TimeGenerated), resolution));
let TimeGenerated_end   = toscalar(t | summarize max(TimeGenerated)) + resolution;
let fictive_connects = t 
| summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, OperationName) by DeviceId 
| where OperationName == "deviceDisconnect"
| extend TimeGenerated = TimeGenerated_start,  OperationName = "deviceConnect";
union t, fictive_connects
| make-series Availability = sum(case(OperationName == "deviceConnect", 1, -1)) on TimeGenerated from TimeGenerated_start to TimeGenerated_end step resolution by DeviceId
| render timechart with (accumulate=true)
```

[image: Basic solution]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42TTU%20DQBCG7yT8hwkniDRStAdpOBhNjBc96M2YZruM7UYWzO5QP%20KPd7aWBiiasuEyO/PM17slEhDkUAjisywxvH9DI0jV1Z3QmFkyqlrFcI0bJfG22BselcYbrJwvFhmHI7El8r0n3wP%20gmIbcVVXFUoKnCne2aYBxG1AGKRJmk6Si0maPiYX2flZliZBtGW0/tfKyhZzDGN2JCP9jzE7ZIz1cvYXY5pkSXIc4/wfxn4ez3PfOz2Fh7ps3HLAkjBkYY0Gfa/kLRq07V0OMz3/tfbWtNgG8TXVVopSmJDgG2yjtTDqC2GpqlDz3wuK4g46ika5WBXcz59cLT4GzAhOOtQd80VJUhtc7BZlHRB8r0sSZrU4qDCGnmYjWH7u9bqNf3dT6jtBnsOhNJwzfpBrp5eBKxkZZAxD5lD13FhTuY2w77A7l0uLV5xYNAotXG6EKsVSlYo%20mcQ9h1LYwXvslN3miGEaw2TKI%20U8/apfTK1HFUD1yAIt4VtXRZ0puloN%206ABJ1K5dpB3RWsIhZSNbkqm5GQajH4AYb4fhlEEAAA=)

Answer (score 0):

Sparse display.
Each device is displayed on another y axis.
10,20,30 etc. stands for disconnected.
15,25,35 etc. stands for connected.

```
let t = datatable(OperationName:string, DeviceId:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    "deviceConnect"    ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:43:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:53:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device2" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:55:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device3" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:00:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device4" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:43:20")
];
// Solution starts here
let resolution = 5m;
let y_axis_devices_distance = 10;
let y_axis_device_states_distance = 5;
let TimeGenerated_start = toscalar(t | summarize bin(min(TimeGenerated), resolution));
let TimeGenerated_end   = toscalar(t | summarize max(TimeGenerated)) + resolution;
let data_points =   toint((bin(TimeGenerated_end, resolution) - bin(TimeGenerated_start, resolution)) / resolution) + 1;
let fictive_connects = 
t 
| summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, OperationName) by DeviceId 
| where OperationName == "deviceDisconnect"
| extend TimeGenerated = TimeGenerated_start,  OperationName = "deviceConnect";
let devices = 
t
| distinct DeviceId
| serialize 
| extend rn = row_number();
union t, fictive_connects
| make-series Availability = y_axis_device_states_distance * sum(case(OperationName == "deviceConnect", 1, -1)) on TimeGenerated from TimeGenerated_start to TimeGenerated_end step resolution by DeviceId
| lookup devices on DeviceId
| extend Availability = array_concat(pack_array(Availability[0] + rn*y_axis_devices_distance), array_slice(Availability, 1, data_points - 1)) 
| render timechart with (accumulate=true)
```

[image: Sparse display]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA41UwW6jQAy9R8o/WDlBCwrQ5tBUHFZbabWX3cP2VlVomLjNKDBEw5A0q/34tQlEQEgUEAJ57Ge/Z5sMLViIYSUs3WmGzu8tGmFVoX%20JHJelNUp/evCCOyXx5%20pkeFU5/kDNvrhaUjhasrjTydt0AnTNVnXE90JrlHbGJq%20xhTPw2gBnFgVR5AdPfhS9Bk/Lx4dlFMzcGqP1f1GlbGFuwVjciBFdw1icY4xxebiEEQbLILgN4/EKxkmP9%20fpZD6HP0VWcXOgtMLYEtZocDrJqIsGy/YshkX%20fLQeEvGlyuSYiN6K4rREcgmDMZeEzm3fcdH49Tqe1Pnp1BalFJkwjoV/UFZ5Loz6i5Aq7eT09IJcr1Ol647iol6RNBdxc/E1wHThvoPaYPI4J9tCaZIoJjzLn46TDividL2iwIdzp5prv3aY96LuIWwyfyhp1Q6TZto4/XRi6emyEOYzOVPHg97quZAeTmtXx%20%2052X0niGM4n3B2xi/LUvYyUC2jxIaYw%20VtRT0O0ZER5%20AhUVraU5k1SzRKZMyyU4bhoTTFPtFVnqJxuPeV5lml9EPJOC4XG/QZivJ92wmViVRlyh4I5vq83rHMjhTl4E/WUaql5UHogR9SM6mOvlAfpshHB94WI/NaWtx296/TOOaSFcWm2p7kI4fuaaPQgKQwRhxYESmssxVyk9QWp%20v2Frzz7Ou7C0tO63aEKTOy90Jr6t0l8YF14HoMVYMG%20Gck10x5r%20waHCFllVcZcY6tqdD9D1lZrPo5BgAA)

Answer (score 0):

Unified display of all devices (number of connected devices)

```
let t = datatable(OperationName:string, DeviceId:string, TimeGenerated:datetime)
[
    "deviceConnect"    ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:43:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device1" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:53:20")
   ,"deviceDisconnect" ,"device2" ,datetime("2022-09-22T09:55:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device3" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:00:20")
   ,"deviceConnect"    ,"device4" ,datetime("2022-09-22T10:43:20")
];
// Solution starts here
let resolution = 5m;
let TimeGenerated_start = toscalar(t | summarize bin(min(TimeGenerated), resolution));
let TimeGenerated_end   = toscalar(t | summarize max(TimeGenerated)) + resolution;
let fictive_connects = t 
| summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, OperationName) by DeviceId 
| where OperationName == "deviceDisconnect"
| extend TimeGenerated = TimeGenerated_start,  OperationName = "deviceConnect";
union t, fictive_connects
| make-series Availability = sum(case(OperationName == "deviceConnect", 1, -1)) on TimeGenerated from TimeGenerated_start to TimeGenerated_end step resolution
| render timechart with (accumulate=true)
```

[image: Unified display]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42TTU%20DQBCG7yT8hwkniDRStAdpOBhNjBc96M2YZruM7UYWzO5QP%20KPd7aWBiiaQrjMzvvMzL5DiQQEORSC%20F2WGN6/oRGk6upOaMwsGVWtYrjGjZJ4W%20wDj0rjDVYuF4uM5UgciXzvyfeAn6DYKq7qqkJJgQvFu9g0gLgVhEGapOkkuZik6WNykZ2fZWkSRFtGm3%20trGwxxzBmRzLS/xizQ8bYLGd/MaZJliTHMc7/Yezv43nue6en8FCXjTMHLAlDFtZo0PdKdtGgbc9ymOn5b7Rn02Ir4mOqrRSlMCHBN9hGa2HUF8JSVaHmryeK4g46ika5WBU8z59cLT4GzAhOOtQd80VJUhtc7IyyDgi%201yUJs1ocdBhDb2cjWH7u93Wrf3e31E%20CPIfD1XDJ%20EFunF4F7mTkImMYModbz4M1lXOEc4fTuVpavOLEolFo4XIjVCmWqlT0ySSeOZTCDv7HTtttjRimMUymfKVcp9/1i6n16AZQPWKgJXzrmOL6MxxHA24x5doJ3xWtIRRSNropWZmTaTD6AWPM9hdFBAAA)